# Add Applications folder to dock using terminal. MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, dock

I'm trying to use AddDockMCXMyApplicationsFolder using terminal commands however i cannot figure out how to syntax it. Help is much appreciated

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array '<dict><key>Dock Payload</key><dict><key>MCXDockSpecialFolders</key><array><string>AddDockMCXMyApplicationsFolder</string></array><key>PayloadDescription</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>AddDockMCXMyApplicationsFolder</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict></dict>'; killall Dock"
```

This is what I have so far and it does not work im assuming cause of syntax and other issues. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `defaults` command. I'm using `persistent-others`, but you can add it as `persistent-apps`. See the [Dock reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/dock) for details.

I'm formatting the input with `\` for reliability, and it should work, but you can also inline it.

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-others -array-add "\
<dict>\
  <key>tile-data</key>\
    <dict>\
      <key>file-data</key>\
        <dict>\
          <key>_CFURLString</key> <string>file:///Applications/</string>\
          <key>_CFURLStringType</key> <integer>15</integer>\
        </dict>\

      <key>file-type</key> <integer>2</integer>\
      <key>showas</key> <integer>1</integer>\
    </dict>\

  <key>tile-type</key> <string>directory-tile</string>\
</dict>"
```

You also need to restart the Dock:

```
killall Dock
```